# Plotly choropleth map is extremely large and slow to load

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, choropleth

I am plotting the regional boundaries of states in Australia.

This renders extremely slowly (10+ minutes) and according to Juputerlab is using up crazy amounts of memory (4Gb+).

I've filtered down the df to a single state to reduce the amount of boundaries to plot. Plotting with a color set to one of the columns takes up even more time and memory. If I don't set a color then it loads in a minute or so.

Is this to be expected? Or is there something I can do with the code so that it renders the map in a reasonable amount of time?

The shape file used can be found [here:](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026/access-and-downloads/digital-boundary-files/SA4_2021_AUST_SHP_GDA94.zip)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.offline as pyo

og_sa4_df = gpd.read_file()
sa4_df = og_sa4_df.copy(deep = True)

sa4_df = sa4_df[sa4_df['STE_NAME21'] == 'New South Wales']
sa4_df.dropna(axis = 0, subset = 'geometry', how = 'any', inplace = True)
sa4_df.set_index('SA4_NAME21')
sa4_df = sa4_df.to_crs(epsg = 4326)
geojson = sa4_df.__geo_interface__  

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(sa4_df,
                              geojson = sa4_df.geometry,
                              locations = sa4_df.index,
                              color = sa4_df.SA4_NAME21,
                              center={"lat": -33.865143, "lon": 151.209900},
                               mapbox_style="carto-positron", 
                               zoom=8,
                              width = 800,
                              height = 500)
    
    fig.show()
```

**SOLUTION**

Using Robs solution in the comments, this sped up the rendering immensely:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

og_sa4_df = gpd.read_file('/Users/kamila/Downloads/SA4_2021_AUST_SHP_GDA94/SA4_2021_AUST_GDA94.shp')
sa4_df = og_sa4_df.copy(deep = True)
geocol = sa4_df.pop('geometry')
sa4_df.insert(0, 'geometry', geocol)
sa4_df = sa4_df[sa4_df['STE_NAME21'] == 'New South Wales']
sa4_df.dropna(axis = 0, subset = 'geometry', how = 'any', inplace = True) #need to drop None value rows for the geometry to be simplified below
sa4_df["geometry"] = (sa4_df.to_crs(sa4_df.estimate_utm_crs()).simplify(1000).to_crs(sa4_df.crs))
sa4_df.set_index('SA4_NAME21')
sa4_df = sa4_df.to_crs(epsg = 4326)
geojson = sa4_df.__geo_interface__

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(sa4_df,
                          geojson = sa4_df.geometry,
                          locations = sa4_df.index,
                          color = sa4_df.SA4_NAME21,
                           color_discrete_map={'Central West': 'red'},
                          center={"lat": -33.865143, "lon": 151.209900},
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron", 
                           zoom=8,
                          width = 1600,
                          height = 800)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite often I find that mapbox slows down very significantly with overly accurate geometry.   Have just taken step to simplify to accuracy of 1000m and then everything runs pretty quickly.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px

sa4_df = gpd.read_file("https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026/access-and-downloads/digital-boundary-files/SA4_2021_AUST_SHP_GDA94.zip")
sa4_df = sa4_df[sa4_df["STE_NAME21"] == "New South Wales"]
# simplify geometry to 1000m accuracy
sa4_df["geometry"] = (
    sa4_df.to_crs(sa4_df.estimate_utm_crs()).simplify(1000).to_crs(sa4_df.crs)
)
sa4_df.dropna(axis=0, subset="geometry", how="any", inplace=True)
sa4_df.set_index("SA4_NAME21")
sa4_df = sa4_df.to_crs(epsg=4326)
geojson = sa4_df.__geo_interface__

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    sa4_df,
    geojson=sa4_df.geometry,
    locations=sa4_df.index,
    color=sa4_df.SA4_NAME21,
    center={"lat": -33.865143, "lon": 151.209900},
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    zoom=8,
    width=800,
    height=500,
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: I thought the problem was due to the complex geometry.

I found that I had to make a slight change to your code to get it working for me, namely running the .dropna before simplifying the geometry as the .estimate_utm.crs() part doesn't work when there are None values in the geometry column